# Best way to count or lookup if any cell in one row matches any cell in other row AND return value from top of row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In this [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cll63IWfeoWIm8kDjNMU5BjS1ZUnB2ZTmMU-3WoVMAg/edit#gid=462519452) I am trying to count the number of different continents and territories being visited.

There is no need to count the same continent more than once. If only one value matches, the loop is supposed to check the next continental column and return the accordingly headlines i.e. 3 (Oceania, Europe, Asia).

What will be the best place to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possbile solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(unq;SPLIT(
             UNIQUE(
               MAP(B3:B;LAMBDA(loc;
                 IF(loc="";;TEXTJOIN(;1;IF(loc=Continents!A2:F;Continents!A1:F1&",C";
                   IF(loc=IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(Territories!A2:F;"(.*) \("));Territories!A1:F1&",T";)))))));",");
       REGEXREPLACE(
         IFNA(SORTN(QUERY(unq;"select count(Col1) where Col2='C'"))&" ("&JOIN(", ";QUERY(unq;"select Col1 where Col2='C'")))&"), "&
           IFNA(SORTN(QUERY(unq;"select count(Col1) where Col2='T'"))&" ("&JOIN(", ";QUERY(unq;"select Col1 where Col2='T'"))&")");
         ", $";)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the desired output. Way over my head. Thank You.

Comment: the interesting parts are this `IF(loc=Continents!A2:F;Continents!A1:F1&",C"` and this `IF(loc=IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(Territories!A2:F;"(.*) \("));Territories!A1:F1&",T"`, the rest of the formula is just formatting the information as requested.

Comment: When i'm applying in my original sheets I get an "Empty request" error. Did I miss something obv.?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like commas Spain, Mallorca

Comment: please replicate the issue in the shared sheet.

Comment: Seems like the comma is doing something. Also I tried to separate Continent from Territory to see the difference.

Comment: what should the corresponding result for row 2 be? There's no "Copenhagen" in Continents or Territories.

Comment: Copenhagen is not supposed to be matched itś just part of testing if thereś a partial match in the query

Comment: Svalbard (Norway) is accepted but not Svalbard, Norway

Comment: which row in the shared spreadsheet?

Comment: 4, 7, 8, 11, 12, 14, 17, 18, 19, 22, 25